# React test with Enzyme, cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

In my React App (No flux / redux), I'm trying to do unit testing to a component using `enzyme`, the **shallow rendering** works well, I am able to retrieve it's state etc, but **mount rendering** throw me an error of `cannot read property 'route' of undefined`.

my `App.js` looks like this

```html
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <MyCustomLayout>
            <Route path="/mypath" component={myComponent} />
          </MyCustomLayout>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
```

Here is the code for `myComponent`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { getList } from './apiService.js';
 
class myComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        myList: [],
      };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
  // get list ajax call
    getList().then(response => {
      this.setState({
        myList: response.data
      })
    });
  }
  
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/home');
  }
  
  renderMyList() {
    /*
      Code for rendering list of items from myList state
    */
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
        {this.renderMyList()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default myComponent
```

Here is the code for my test

```js
import React from 'react';
import myComponent from './myComponent';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';

test('Initial state of myList should be empty array ', () => {
  const component = shallow(<myComponent/>);
  expect(component.state().myList).toEqual([]);
});

test('Make sure the componentDidMount being called after mount', () => {
  sinon.spy(myComponent.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
  const component = mount(<myComponent/>);
  expect(myComponent.prototype.componentDidMount.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
});
```

What does the error ?

Comment: You should use `MemoryRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` for unit tests. Your issue is probably related to this. Could you show the code for your test?

Comment: So what you're suggesting is that I should alter the real implementation just for the sake of unit test ? I don't think it's a good idea.

Anyway, I added the test, please have a look @LukeVella

Comment: It would be useful to see what's in `myComponent`.

Comment: @LukeVella edited again

Comment: I don't see anything but you must be referring to `route` somewhere. Maybe post the stack trace of the error.

Comment: Anyway, `MemoryRouter` doesn't seem to be fixing my problem, I simply changed from `BrowserRouter` to `MemoryRouter` in my `app.js`, am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148858/discussion-between-matt-downey-and-luke-vella).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had this issue here the other day - the reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to mount a `<Route />` or a `<Link />` or a component wrapped with `withRouter()` when there's no `<Router />` surrounding the code. These components are expecting a certain context to be there (which `<Router />` provides), so in order to test these components, you have to mount the component inside a `<MemoryRouter />`.

Here's a function that does this for you:

```
const mountWithRouter = Component => mount(
  <MemoryRouter>
    {Component}
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```

And here's how you use it:

```
test('Make sure the componentDidMount being called after mount', () => {
  sinon.spy(myComponent.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
  const component = mountWithRouter(<myComponent/>);
  expect(myComponent.prototype.componentDidMount.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
});
```

That being said, I ended up trying to remove most of my mounted test code when migrating to `react-router@^4.0.0` - it's a lot of hassle. The major downside of this is that your `const component` in this test no longer is a `myComponent`, but a `MemoryRouter`. That means you can't dig into its state etc quite as easily.

Edit:

An example of what I did when I did need to check the state of a component that I "had" to mount was that I shallow-rendered it instead, and then ran the life cycle methods I needed manually, like this:

```
test('populates state on componentDidMount', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
  expect(wrapper.state()).toBe({ some: 'state' });
});
```

This way, I don't have to deal with the router issue at all (since no mount), and I still get to test what I need to test.

Comment: I know it's out of the main topic, but right now, I am facing the problem you're talking about, I couldn't retrieve the component's state if it's wrapped in `MemoryRouter`, can you show me the way to deal with this issue ?

Comment: @MattDowney - I added another example on how I dealt with that challenge. Not sure if it is the best approach, but it's what I came up with.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you are able to call `componentDidMount` in a shallow rendered component.

Comment: Was news to me as well! But it is a simple method - even though React calls it for us, it's still a part of the prototype :)